# Have no permissions for files created inside docker on ubuntu (Linux mint)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, linux-mint

I don't have permissions for every file that has been created inside a docker container.

For example,

Inside a php container for a laravel project,  executing `php artisan make:model SomeModel` will create the php file **SomeModel.php** as **root user**, so when I try to change or delete it in my OS (Linux mint) I can't because my user has no root permissions.

In Windows it worked without this headache, how to avoid it on Linux mint?

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably because in your docker, you run programs (php artisan in this case) as the root: see the figure, you have `root@...:/code/app#` showing that.

My suggestion is: in your docker file, you add another user with proper permissions (you may have it done already) and just before running the php artisan command, you change the current user from root to the added user (with *su - user* command) and then run the command.